# Increment count in a table while inserting value in another table

Tags: java, hibernate

I developed a java web application which contains Wallpapers, there is like button for each wallpaper, If a user clicks on like then I am storing userId,wallpaperId and like count in 'User_Wallpaper' table, and I have another table 'wall_stats' which contains statistics for wallpaers, i.e total liked wallpapers.
So,What I want...
If user clicks like button then I have to update in 'User_Wallpaper' and also increment the count in 'wall_stats'....How can I do this?
I am using Hibernate 3.0.
Please help me...thanks in advance.... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you are storing the "like count" in the `User_Wallpaper` table (can a user "like" a wallpaper more than once?) but rather than creating a new table for the `wall_stats`, I'd make `wall_stats` a view:

```
 CREATE TABLE User_Likes_Wallpaper (
     userId NUMBER(10) not null,
     wallpaperId NUMBER(10) not null);

 CREATE VIEW Wall_stats AS
     SELECT wallpaperId, count(*)
       FROM User_Likes_Wallpaper
      GROUP BY wallpaperId
```

That way the wall_stats is always up-to-date... (though you probably want an indexes on `User_Likes_Wallpaper`)

Comment: thanks for ur reply benny23.... :)
View is not useful :-( , I want to update the count in the 'Wall_stats' table....
and I also have more fields in 'Wall_stats' table....

Answer (score 0):

You can go for Trigger. A trigger on insert of `User_Wallpaper` table can do update on `wall_stats` table.